# How do i test the length of a var in batch?

Tags: batch-file, string-length

I basically need to test how long a variable is in a batch file. Example:

```
@echo off
set /p someVar=""
//some code to figure out how long it is
cls
echo someVar is %length% characters long.
pause
exit
```

So if I type

```
Batch files
```

it will say

```
someVar is 10 characters long.
```

Comment: I'm not a batch scripter, but Google gives this: http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/514228

Comment: Isn't the string "Batch files" 11 characters long?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link provided by @minitech, here is a script which should work:

```
@echo off
set /p someVar=""

::some code to figure out how long it is

::Start by writing the file to a temp file
echo %someVar%>"%temp%\tmp.txt" 

:: get the files size in bytes and subtract 3 for the trailing space and newline and delete the temp file
for %%a in (%temp%\tmp.txt) do set /a length=%%~za & set /a length -=3 & del "%temp%\tmp.txt"

cls

echo someVar is %length% characters long.

pause

exit
```